# curl hangs during http download

Tags: curl, tcp

I have a VM running CentOS 6. On this Linux box, I run 4 curl download concurrently.

In some case, one of the curl download hangs. `ps` shows that curl process is still there. And `netstat` shows the connection's RECV_Q is very long:

```
tcp   878104      0 10.161.238.20:46130         10.162.220.12:80            ESTABLISHED
```

The `curl` version 7.38.0.

Any idea? Why `curl` hangs? If increasing TCP buffer would help?

Comment: It seems you are not too "rapid" to get data from Recv_q. Could you please use the `--trace` option to see what it gets out? It seems your host is not able to get data from the socket. Curl parallel execution are for the same data or are they different calls ?

Comment: Could be any number of reasons, but my first guess would be PMTU fun caused by somebody blocking ICMPs between you and the server.

Comment: @SatoKatsura can you please give more details? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you don't know what PMTU discovery is and what that has to do with ICMPs I'm afraid I don't have a quick solution for you.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Large and static receive queue indicates data has been received on the socket but curl is not reading it.

There's no reason increasing TCP buffers would help.

It is a pathological case here. For an HTTP request, curl is meant to send a request (or possibly requests if chunked) and read the response. If it's not reading the response, it's either it's suspended or its busy doing something else.

That could be for instance because it's blocked writing the response to its standard output, for instance because it's a full pipe, or it's writing it  to a file on an unreliable network filesystem.

```
ps -o state,wchan,args -C curl
```

Or

```
pgrep -x curl | xargs -IP cat /proc/P/stack
```

Might give you a clue as to what `curl` is doing that prevents it from reading  the response (also `/proc/$pid/task/*/stack` for multithreaded applications).

Answer (score 0):

You could try running `curl` with `strace` and/or try with the latest version of `curl` (version 7.50.3).

Comment: Coz this is a production environment, I cannot run `curl` with `strace`. And since this issue is hard to reproduce, it's hard to debug with single test.

Comment: You can statically compile `strace` and copy it over to the production environment, unless there are weird company policies in place.